# Getting "No module named django_messages"

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, pip

I'm working with a Django app, called [DjangoBB](http://djangobb.org/).  I'm trying to install it on my server, but I'm getting stuck with the messages plugin/app.

This output doesn't make any sense to me...

```
# pip install django-messages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-messages in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
# python manage.py runserver
Error: No module named django_messages
```

I had the same problem with other modules, like django-registration, and django_notifications, but I just popped them into `pip` and then went through again and got a new missing dependency.  It's stuck here though.  Any ideas?

---

My INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'registration',
    'pagination',
    'django_authopenid',
    'djangobb_forum',
    'haystack',
    'django_messages',
)
```

Comment: Another idea to help narrow this down.  If you run './manage.py shell' and then type 'import django_messages' what happens?

Comment: A few more to help narrow this down:  Do other manage.py commands like validate and syncdb fail with the same error?  Are you using a virtualenv, and if so is it activated?

Comment: @Nathan, All valid `mangage.py` commands give the same error (I've tried syncdb, runserver, validate, and shell).

Comment: This also happens if you do something dumb like install django 1.1 instead of django 1.10, say through a pip requirements file where you left out a zero. I didn't make an embarrassing error like that, of course, it was a... uh friend that did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual app is called `'messages'`. Make sure you add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Strange... `django_messages` works on my local machine, but `messages` appears to be required by my server.  Both based on Ubuntu 12.10.  Any way I can alias it on my local machine, so that I don't have inconsistent code?

Comment: @redDragonzz, I think I must be looking for a different module.  I don't remember how I installed it locally...

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add 'django_messages' to your list of INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Comment: `'django_messages'` is in the INSTALLED_APPS.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

On my server I had version 0.4.4.  On my local machine I had version 0.5.0.pre.

The code for that isn't available through pip, but the BB app requires it.  I somehow downloaded it [from here](https://github.com/arneb/django-messages) and ran `python setup.py install`.

Now the messages module is unavailable, but `django_messages` is exposed.

Comment: Nice, glad you were able to figure out the root of the problem.  FYI if you wanted to install from that github link using pip you could do: **pip install git+git://github.com/arneb/django-messages**.

Comment: @NathanJhaveri, thanks.  I noticed it was in my app's requirements.txt after I added this answer.